# Replace multiple %in% statements with a single line of dplyr code

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a flag that is 1 if any one of 13 columns contains any one of a large number of codes and is 0 otherwise. I need to use dplyr because my data is in database. I can accomplish what I'm after using many %in% statements. I am wondering if there is a more concise way to write this code. Is there a version of %in% that allows multiple variables on the left hand side?

The following code gives the correct result. I've included only 5 columns and 2 rows for brevity.

```
library(dplyr)

match_dx <- c(paste0("C0", 0:9), paste0("C", 10:20))

df <- tibble(dx1 = c("C00", "G01"),
   dx2 = c("C50", "Z11"),
   dx3 = c("D20", "D22"),
   dx4 = c("A40", "C21"),
   dx13 = c("G20", "C30"))

df %>% 
 mutate(flag = case_when(
      dx1 %in% match_dx ~ 1,
      dx2 %in% match_dx ~ 1,
      dx3 %in% match_dx ~ 1,
      dx4 %in% match_dx ~ 1,
      dx13 %in% match_dx ~ 1,
      T ~ 0
 ))
```

I would like to know if there is something like

```
df %>% 
 mutate(flag = case_when(
      any(vars(dx1:dx13) %in% match_dx) ~ 1,
      T ~ 0
 ))
```

This does work but perhaps there is something similar or another way to accomplish this without needing one line per variable.

Thanks!

Comment: You should likely `microbenchmark` the various answers. My bet is the `apply` one is fastest & uses the least memory.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I'm trying them out. Keep in mind I'm using a database backend so the dplyr code has to translate to SQL.

Comment: @thelatemail did you supply an answer? I don't see one.

Comment: @AdamBlack I missed the part abt db back-end. Mine won't work there.

Comment: Not rly an answer @thelatemail but his code is the right one for the DB ops. So if you feel the need to be right, yay!

Comment: @hrbrmstr I cannot seem to use reduce or Reduce to generate SQL in a tbl_dbi / dplyr pipeline. Still working on it.

Comment: Hrm. lemme try it against a DB today. that (valid) restriction does make some ops more gnarly.

Comment: maybe something like mutate_all(funs(. %in% match_dx)) %>% mutate(flag = any(dx1, dx2, dx3, dx4, dx13))

Answer (score 4):

Here is one option by `gather`ing to 'long' format and then `spread` it to 'wide'

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
    gather(key, val, -rn) %>% group_by(rn) %>%
    mutate(flag = as.integer(any(val %in% match_dx))) %>%
    spread(key, val)
# A tibble: 2 x 7 
# Groups:   rn [2]
#     rn  flag   dx1  dx13   dx2   dx3   dx4
#* <chr> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1     1     1   C00   G20   C50   D20   A40
#2     2     0   G01   C30   Z11   D22   C21
```

---

Or by using `mutate_all` to create logical columns, then `reduce` it to single logical vector and `mutate` to create the 'flag'

```
df %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(. %in% match_dx)) %>% 
  reduce(`|`) %>%
  as.integer %>%
  mutate(df, flag = .)
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#     dx1   dx2   dx3   dx4  dx13  flag
#    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
#1   C00   C50   D20   A40   G20     1
#2   G01   Z11   D22   C21   C30     0
```

---

Or use the `Reduce/lapply` `base R` option suggested by @thelatemail

```
df$flag <- as.integer(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df, is.element, set=match_dx)))
```

Or using `%in%`

```
as.integer(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df, `%in%`, match_dx)))
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `Reduce` in base R, but you essentially cover this anyway with option #2 - for posterity's sake, it is: `as.integer(Reduce(\`|\`, lapply(df, is.element, set=match_dx)))`

Comment: @thelatemail  I guess `is.element` is similar to `%in%`

Comment: It's identical I believe - it just avoids the need for more ```` backticks

Answer (score 3):

We can use `apply` with `mutate` to compare all columns at once.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(flag = apply(., 1, function(x) any(x %in% match_dx) * 1))
# # A tibble: 2 x 6
#     dx1   dx2   dx3   dx4  dx13  flag
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
# 1   C00   C50   D20   A40   G20     1
# 2   G01   Z11   D22   C21   C30     0
```

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: I overlooked the need for these to be in-db SQL ops. This won't work for that.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrrlyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  by_row(~{ as.numeric(any(. %in% match_dx)) }, .to="flag") %>% 
  mutate(flag = flatten_dbl(flag))
## # A tibble: 2 x 6
##     dx1   dx2   dx3   dx4  dx13  flag
##   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
## 1   C00   C50   D20   A40   G20     1
## 2   G01   Z11   D22   C21   C30     0
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another alternative using `purrr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% mutate(flag = map_int(transpose(.), ~ any(. %in% match_dx)))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>     dx1   dx2   dx3   dx4  dx13  flag
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
#> 1   C00   C50   D20   A40   G20     1
#> 2   G01   Z11   D22   C21   C30     0
```